# Evaluating $ \lim\limits_{x\to 0} \left(\frac{x^4 + 2 x^3 + x^2}{{\tan}^{-1} x}\right)$

Tags: limits, functions, trigonometry, limits-without-lhopital, inverse-function

In a question from a class test,  we are given this function:
$$f(x) =
\begin{cases}
\frac{x^4 + 2 x^3 + x^2}{{\tan}^{-1} x},  & \text{if $ x \neq 0$} \\[2ex]
0, & \text{if $x = 0$}
\end{cases}$$
We are asked to find whether $f(x)$ is continuous at $x=0$
.

Now, we can get the solution by Taylor expansion or L'Hopital's rule quite easily.
But, L'Hopital's rule and Taylor expansions aren't a part of my course syllabi this year so I don't think they need to be applied here.

But I can't figure out how to evaluate this:
$$\lim_{x \to 0} \left(\frac{x^4 + 2 x^3 + x^2}{{\tan}^{-1}  x}\right)$$ without these methods.

I think the first step should be factorizing the numerator to get 
$$f(x) =  \frac {x^2(x+1)^2}{{\tan}^{-1}x}$$

Now I don't know how to proceed further.
Is there some identity that can be used here?

Comment: With $x=\tan u$ we get $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\arctan x}{x}=\lim_{u \to 0} \frac{u}{\tan u}=\lim_{u \to 0} \frac{1}{\frac{\sin u}{u}} \cos u=1$. @Mr Reality

Comment: @Ahmed S. Attaalla, oh okay. Thanks for explaining!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the derivative :

$\displaystyle \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\arctan(x)- \arctan(0)}{x-0}=f'(0)=\dfrac{1}{1+(0)^2}=1\iff \displaystyle \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\arctan(x)}{x}=1$

Thus :

$\displaystyle \lim_{x \to 0} \dfrac{x^4 + 2 x^3 + x^2}{\arctan x}=\lim_{x \to 0} \dfrac{x^3 + 2 x^2 + x}{\frac{\arctan(x)}{x}}=0$

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But this answer uses the same method for solving the problem as the previous answer.

Comment: But I don't use L'Hopital rule!!!

Comment: I use the definition of a derivative :$$\lim_{x\to x_0}\dfrac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0}=f'(x_0)$$

Comment: Okay, I think I didn't read it carefully enough.

Comment: +1 ( I would surely have accepted this answer if you had written it earlier) ;)

Comment: you can upvote       .

Comment: Well, I already have. ;) (Clue: see the no. of reputations I have)

Answer (score 1):

Divide both numerator and denominator by x , 
and we know $$\lim_{x \to 0 }( (\arctan(x) ) /x )  = 1 $$

Thus the limit becomes 
 $$ \lim_{x \to 0 } x^3 + 2x^2 + x   = 0 $$

For the 1st limit,
$$ \arctan(x) = x - (1/3) x^3 + (1/5)x^5 +..$$

Thus taking L Hospital here 
$$ \lim_{x \to 0 }( (\arctan(x) ) /x )   $$ becomes

$$ \lim_{x \to 0 } ( 1 - x^2 ) /1 =1 $$

Comment: Ok, I did not know about the identity for arctan(x) that you used. Do you know of any source when I can read up on a simple proof of this identity? (I see it can be proved by applying L'Hopital's rule: can that be taken as a valid proof?)

Comment: I edited my answer. Hope you get it.

Comment: I suggest you learn how to typeset if you haven't already @Sitanshu. To type $\lim_{x \to a} f(x)$ write \lim_{x \to a} f(x).

Comment: @Ahmed S. Attaalla, Then I just get $\frac{u}{tan (u)}$. In a sense that's just the numerator and denominator interchanged, right? What do I need to do now?

Comment: @Ahmed S. Attaalla Thanks. Will do that. Sorry for the trouble.

Comment: No need to apologize! (+1 for the simple but effective answer).

Comment: @Sitanshu, can't we apply L'hopital's rule in the first step itself so that the expression reduces to: $$\lim_{x\to0} \frac{1}{1 + x^2} = \frac{1}{1 + (0)} = 1$$

Comment: Yes , we can apply L hospital in the 1st step itself. But , whenever, arctanx given, try to remove it by dividing x and then see what the equation becomes. But, whatever you did is right too.

Comment: Your application of l'Hospital looks very strange to me. It looks like you keep the first two terms of the series expansion. Isn't it better (or if you want, more correct) to use the well-known fact that the derivative of $\arctan x$ is $1/(1+x^2)$?

Comment: Yes, either way, it can be done. I was trying to do it by expansion method.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the help! I'm "accepting" it.

Comment: Sitanshu, I think you should consider including Ahmed's proof for $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{arctan(x)}{x} = 1$. I concur with mickep's opinion that what you have is unclear as at the last step you dropped all the other terms apart from $1-x^2$.